# Error while trying to launch node.js applicaation with pm2:

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, express, pm2

[Getting this in pm2 logs, already restarted & killed & flushed logs but still, the problem persists.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVpXf.png)

This error occurred while I tried to deploy my application while running pm2.

```
[TAILING] Tailing last 15 lines for [all] processes (change the value with --lines option)
/home/ubuntu/.pm2/pm2.log last 15 lines:
PM2        | 2021-05-13T07:04:37: PM2 log: App [index:0] online
PM2        | 2021-05-13T07:04:37: PM2 log: App [index:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2021-05-13T07:04:37: PM2 log: App [index:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2021-05-13T07:04:37: PM2 log: App [index:0] online
PM2        | 2021-05-13T07:04:37: PM2 log: App [index:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2021-05-13T07:04:37: PM2 log: App [index:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2021-05-13T07:04:37: PM2 log: App [index:0] online
PM2        | 2021-05-13T07:04:37: PM2 log: App [index:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2021-05-13T07:04:37: PM2 log: App [index:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2021-05-13T07:04:38: PM2 log: App [index:0] online
PM2        | 2021-05-13T07:04:38: PM2 log: App [index:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2021-05-13T07:04:38: PM2 log: App [index:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2021-05-13T07:04:38: PM2 log: App [index:0] online
PM2        | 2021-05-13T07:04:38: PM2 log: App [index:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2021-05-13T07:04:38: PM2 log: Script /home/ubuntu/M-9/index.js had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"

/home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/index-out.log last 15 lines:
/home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/index-error.log last 15 lines:
0|index    | Require stack:
0|index    | - /home/ubuntu/M-9/index.js
0|index    |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1030:15)
0|index    |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:61:29)
0|index    |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
0|index    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/M-9/index.js:1:17)
0|index    |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1201:30)
0|index    |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1221:10)
0|index    |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1050:32)
0|index    |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:938:14)
0|index    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:33:23)
0|index    |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1201:30) {
0|index    |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
0|index    |   requireStack: [ '/home/ubuntu/M-9/index.js' ]
0|index    | }
```

Comment: There is module problem. Have you tried to reinstall the node_modules? If yes and the error still exist, can you try to run the program manually on the server and see if the problem still exists?

Comment: Nope didn't work even after reinstalling it, it does work while running manually although that is why it is so confusing. Also, I haven't changed a single line of code but now styling & other js files have not been found error has been showing. It's totally unrelated to what was happening earlier.

Comment: If you can run it manually without problem, it should be related to pm2. May try to reinstall pm2 or test out an alternative called forever. https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Comment: Certain issues with my code I think, I tried the sample one it worked fine & is deployed but CSS & JS files are not found error is showed in console now.